# Asp.netMVC5 using Mysql

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]

In Asp.netmvc I have 2 different table - so I Created 2 model then I need show In SingleView Sothen I Create new Model with those 2 Model Integrated then I pass value through controller

Answer (score 0):

you will nee to create a new tbl_address object and assign address1 to it and then assign tbl_address  object back to obj.tbl_address.

same goes for tbl_user

the obj.tbl_address and obj.tbl_address are not initiated when you create a new obj

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
    EmployeeDetails obj = new EmployeeDetails(); 
    tbl_address oAddress = new tbl_address();
    oAddress.Addr_Address = "hello";

    obj.tbl_address = tbl_address;

    return View(obj); 

}
```

Comment: If U dont'nt Mind Can U share Ur Email ID Or Skype Id I will Share Screen Wr I Was Struck

Comment: I Solve it thnks for helping

Comment: what was the problem?